# Why does datatype convert < long oldTimestamp = Convert.ToInt64(values) > return error ? unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an error from running this script :

```
long timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
string values = PlayerPrefs.GetString("margaretSellTimer1");
long oldTimestamp = Convert.ToInt64(values);
long elapsedSeconds = Convert.ToInt64(timestamp) - oldTimestamp;

string value = PlayerPrefs.GetString("margaretSellTimer");
long oldTickTime = Convert.ToInt64(value);
oldTickTime = oldTickTime + elapsedSeconds;
```

The line :

```
long timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
```

returns error :

```
Assets/script/margaretSellTimer.cs(138,22): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type double to long. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The line :

```
long oldTimestamp = Convert.ToInt64(values);
```

returns error :

```
Input string was not in the correct format
```

Why is this an error? I have made a converter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `TotalSeconds` is a `double` not `long`. Simply replace `long timestamp` with `double timestamp`.

```
double timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
```

Or cast the `double` to `long` with (long).

```
long timestamp = (long) (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
```

You could also do it the way Jeppe mentioned in the comment, which prevents unnecessary datatype conversion.

```
long timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
```

Comment: Yeah, thats work man.. Thanks I just can't figured out what is the problem.

Comment: Maybe use: `(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`. This avoids going through a floating-point. Much cleaner.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's another good way. Added that to the solution.

Comment: @DennisLiu Now that I come to think of it, the BCL has built in support for this nowadays (since .NET 4.6, Visual Studio 2015). Simply say `long timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();`. No need for your own "formula" then. [Documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds.aspx)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen He can't use anything from C# NET 4.6 in yet. Unity is still using C# 3.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

For your casting error:

If you look at the documentation of the [TimeSpan class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` is a `double`. And c# does not allow to implicitly cast to `long`. So you either change the datatype of timestamp to `double timestamp` or you explicitly cast.

```
long timestamp = (long) (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
```

For your conversion error:

The result of `value = PlayerPrefs.GetString("margaretSellTimer")` is something that cannot be parsed into a `long`, because it contains illegal characters or it may for instance be a double. Make a breakpoint in the line of the conversion and inspect the content of `value`.